# Web Api 2: Custom parameter validation (typeconverter)

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2, typeconverter

In Web Api 2, a method on a controller can have a number of parameters supplied from the URI, e.g. string converted to int and automatic web error message returned if string could not be converted to int.

I would like to do the same with a custom type. I have created a class that holds just a DateTime object and I want to make a custom conversion of the web URI string argument to this DateTime object. For this I implemented a TypeConverter. It works. My problem is that if I give it a bad date string, I get no web error and my method gets a null pointer. This is my model with the typeconverter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DkDateTimeConverter))]
public class DkDateTime
{
    private static readonly ILog log4 = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public DateTime dkDateTime;

    public static bool TryParse(string s, out DkDateTime result)
    {
        log4.Debug("TryParse");
        result = null;

        var culture = new CultureInfo("da");
        try
        {
            result = new DkDateTime()
            {
                dkDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture)
            };
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class DkDateTimeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private static readonly ILog log4 = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        log4.Debug("CanConvertFrom");
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        log4.Debug("ConvertFrom");
        if (value is string)
        {
            DkDateTime dkDateTime;
            if (DkDateTime.TryParse((string)value, out dkDateTime))
            {
                return dkDateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                log4.Debug("Exception");
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

My Controller has this method as entry point:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid messageid, int statuscode, DkDateTime sentdate, DkDateTime donedate)
```

I was under the impression that if ConvertFrom caused an exception, this would be reflected by web api and an web error message would be sent back to the caller. If I give "2a" as statuscode, I do get a web error like this:

```
<Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
```

How do I trigger the same error message with my typeconverter? Perhaps a typeconverter cannot help, but which way should I then look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct and it is by design. Think of what you would expect from an invalid `Guid` in the `messageid` param. Same thing happens there. Either the route wont match or you get an invalid request. In order to have more control over the model state validation & error message you should inherit from `IModelBinder` and build your custom `DkDateTimeModelBinder`.

Check this post: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

**Update with example**.

```
public class DkDateTime
{
    public DateTime dkDateTime;

    public static bool TryParse(string s, out DkDateTime result) {
        result = null;
        var dateTime = default(DateTime);
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dateTime)) {
            result = new DkDateTime { dkDateTime = dateTime };
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

 public class DkDateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(DkDateTime)) {
            return false;
        }

        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (val == null) {
            return false;
        }

        string key = val.RawValue as string;
        if (key == null) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                bindingContext.ModelName, "Wrong value type");
            return false;
        }

        DkDateTime result;
        if (DkDateTime.TryParse(key, out result)) {
            bindingContext.Model = result;
            return true;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
            bindingContext.ModelName, "Cannot convert value to DkDateTime");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("test")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDk([ModelBinder(typeof(DkDateTimeModelBinder))]DkDateTime sendDate) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok(sendDate);
    }
}
```

Now when I test with url `http://localhost:4814/example/test?senddate=dsfasdafsd` I get the expected respose below

Status 400 Bad Request

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "sendDate": [
            "Cannot convert value to DkDateTime"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if I give a bad guid on the URI, I get a web error returned, just like with a bad integer. I am looking to get my custom object to cause the same error. If ModelBinder is the way to do that, I'll look into that.

Comment: I implemented the ModelBinder example provided by your link and at first it didn't work. But when I replaced the last "return false" with throw FormatException, I did get a web error returned. Thanks. :)

Comment: glad to be able to help

Comment: The is one difference, though: Instead of the "The request is invalid." error message, I get "An error has occurred.". Apparently I am still not quite there yet.

Comment: this is not true as far as I can tell. I just did a quick test and my json response looks like: `{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "sentdate": [
      "Cannot convert value to DKDate"
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: also no need to throw FormatException there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92834/discussion-between-galmok-and-cleftheris).